# How to extract only the number from a variable

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have an IBM Cloud Function that returns the following input in my variable.

```
$nights "{"nights":2}"
```

I'd like to extract only the number from the variable so that when I call it like so:

```
Number Of Nights: $nights
```

It would show 
:

```
Number Of Nights: 2
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

- `Number of Nights: <? $nights["nights"] ?>`
- `Number of Nights: <? $nights.nights ?>`

There are even more options, see here in the [IBM Watson Assistant docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-shorthand-context) and [here](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods).